# Migrations error in Django after moving to new server

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I'm developing a Django 1.8 application locally and having reached a certain point a few days ago, I uploaded the app to a staging server, ran migrations, imported the sql dump, etc. and all was fine.

I've since resumed local development which included the creation of a new model, and changing some columns on an existing model. I ran the migrations locally with success, but after rsync-ing my files to the staging server, I get a 'relation already exists' error when running `manage.py migrate`. And when I visit the admin page for the new model, I get a 'column does not exist' error.

It seems as though the migrations for this model were partially successful but I cannot migrate the entirety of the model schema. I've tried commenting out parts of the migration files, but was not successful.  Would it be possible to create the missing columns via psql? Or is there some way of determining what is missing and then manually write a migration to create the missing database structure?

I'm using Django 1.8.6, Python 3.4.3, and PostgreSQL 9.3.6. Any advice on this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your migration file, your model and your current database structure? If you can, limit it please to fields/models which are affected by that error.

Comment: Can you post the output of `manage.py migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `migrate --fake-initial` since you're getting the "relation already exists" error. Failing that, I would manually back up each one of my migration folders, remove them from the server, then re-generate migration files for each app and run them all again from scratch (i.e., the initial `makemigrations`).